# External JavaScript Not Working properly in Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular

Hi i want to help in Angular 5. I am using external java scripts files without using node modules for Owl.Carousel. but the Owl.Carousel are not working. In `angular-cli.json` i have link my js files like this

```js
"scripts": [

        "././assets/js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js",
        "././assets/js/Owl.Carousel.js",
        "././assets/js/slick.min.js",
        "././assets/js/active.js"
      ],
```

I have also try to embed the js file in `index.html` like this

```html
<body>
 <app-root></app-root>
 
    <script src="././assets/js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
   
    <script src="././assets/js/Owl.Carousel.js"></script>
    
    <script src="././assets/js/slick.min.js"></script>
  
    <script src="././assets/js/active.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

But both of these way doesn't work and Owl.Carousel not working. And also i don't have to show any error in my console. [My project structure is like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5yt4.png)

Comment: Try `assets/js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js` and another links in `angular-cli.json`

Answer (score 1):

Angular team advise don't to use jQuery with Angular. jQuery was originally designed as a DOM manipulation library and Angular Team say this is a practice not recommended.

I usually use a Bootstrap Directive for Carrousel:

https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/carousel/examples.

It's simple to use and you archieve awesomes results:

```
 <ngb-carousel>
  <ng-template ngbSlide>
    <img src="https://lorempixel.com/900/500?r=1" alt="Random first slide">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h3>First slide label</h3>
      <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template ngbSlide>
    <img src="https://lorempixel.com/900/500?r=2" alt="Random second slide">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h3>Second slide label</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template ngbSlide>
    <img src="https://lorempixel.com/900/500?r=3" alt="Random third slide">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h3>Third slide label</h3>
      <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur.</p>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
</ngb-carousel>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add external JS and CSS to the assets folder and link them in the `.angular-cli.json` as below:

```
assets/js/my-js-file.js
```

If your files are linked properly then you'll have to initialize the carousel in the `AfterViewInit` lifecycle hook.

Working example:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/owl-carousel-example

Comment: i have also link my files in angular-cli.json but not working..then i have put my files in index.html before </body> tag

Comment: Have you checked in the Network section in the Developer Tools, that are those files loaded successfully or not?

Comment: @SamMalik: Please check the updated answer with working example.

Answer (score 1):

As Angular team discourage developers to use javascript in your application. You can use it if you found no other solution than 
And your file path should be like this

```
<script src="assets/js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/Owl.Carousel.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/slick.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/active.js"></script>
```